# How can I make a dotted line separator in an MFC dialog?

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there a control for this anywhere? Or a way to use another control to make it look like a separator?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the OnPaint function of your dialog and have it draw the line. Ordinarily the OnPaint for a dialog doesn't do anything, as all the content is in controls which paint themselves.

Comment: Ended up doing this using a CPen and the "dash" line style and the LineTo method. Does everything for you.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the image control and change the color property to 'Etched'. Resize the control so it just looks like single line.

Comment: Not a "dotted" line, but certainly the simplest way to put a line on a dialog.

Comment: @Mark I went with 'control' and 'separator', I am not sure if I have even seen a dotted line like that but this usually accomplishes the task.

Comment: To clarify: at least as of Visual Studio 2017 it is called "Picture Control."  Change the property "Color" to "Etched" on the property dialog.

Comment: Set Static Edge=true to avoid 1-pixel dot on the left